# ObservalbeCollection.Orderby items changed in ordered collection

Tags: wpf

I have a ObservableCollection that i want to sort:

```
        public ObservableCollection<AstratecRecipe> AstratecReceptenHMIUnSorted { get; set; }
```

The sorted collection will be :

```
        private ObservableCollection<AstratecRecipe> _astratecRecipesHMI;

    public ObservableCollection<AstratecRecipe> AstratecReceptenHMI
    {
        get { return _astratecRecipesHMI; }
        set
        {
            _astratecRecipesHMI = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AstratecReceptenHMI);
        }
    }
```

Every BlokT(int) property deep down in all of the AstratecRecepten in the sorted collection is changed to -2147483648 although BlokT has the correct value in the 'unsorted' collection !

[image: Unsorted collection]

After sorting :
[image]

-2147483648 is  FFFF FFFF 8000 000

Kind Regards
Johan

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!

I compared the wrong items !!
There was indeed a calculation problem in the Aluminium recipes !

Johan